# How to plot those equations in julia?

Tags: plot, julia

I tried to plot it but i got many errors

```
using Winston

p1(Prm)=(Prm-0.25)*min(1.5-Prm,0.50)

p2(Prm)=0.5*(Prm-0.25)*min(1.5-Prm,0.50)

p3(Prm)=(Prm-0.25)*min(2.00-Prm,0.50)

plot(p1,p2,p3)
```

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: @TZHX when i do that plot(1.30,p1_MW,1.30,p2_MW,1.30,p1_MW)                          I got an error"expected array of function for argument #1;got float64"

Comment: The code in the question doesn't make sense, how does `plot()` know what to plot? Those curly braces `{` `}` aren't valid Julia syntax.

Comment: I want to plot p1,p2 and p3 equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for example

```
plot(p1,0,10,p2,0,10,p3,0,10)
```

When plotting a function with Winston you need to specify an xrange for the plot. The example above will generate a plot for an xrange 0...10.